# Multiple input line

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

Trying to obtain this

```
    Algorithm 1 : Name of algorithm

    Input: Input number 1
           Input number 2
           Input number 3 that extend the length desired
           so can it brought to the next line
    Output: Output
    Begin
    Some intelligent algorithm
    End
```

so far I've got

```
    \newlength\mylen
     \newcommand\myinput[1]{%
     \settowidth\mylen{\KwIn{}}%
     \setlength\hangindent{\mylen}%
     \hspace*{\mylen}#1\\}
    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm caption}\label{alg:cap}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \KwIn{data:first long input}
    \myinput{Second input line}
    \myinput{third input line}
    \myinpur{fourth input line that is really long and needs to be broken down}
    \KwOut{the output line}  
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

it's not working at all

[image: Here is what i get when i run this code]

[image: here are some of the errors]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you could (a) explain further how it is not working, what are you expecting and what does it look like (preferably with an image please) and (b) extend your code fragment into a small, compilable example that we can copy and paste into our own systems to trial solutions and examine the issues please. It helps people help you quicker :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `algpseudocodex`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm caption}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require{data:first long input\\%
data:first long input\\%
Second input line\\%
third input line\\%
fourth input line that is really long and needs to be broken down}
\Ensure{the output line}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way we can align this. Also, is \begin{document} necessary immediately after \algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}.

Comment: @user529674 I don't quite understand what you mean. Package `algpseudocodex` can meet your needs and its usage is very simple. You can check the corresponding manual. `\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}` is just for modifying the displayed content, it can be placed anywhere.